# Tkinter: binding the same key to different widgets

Tags: python, widget, key, tkinter, bind

Is there a way to bind the same key to two different widgets in Tkinter?

regards,

jacopo

Comment: what problem are you really trying to solve? Do you need the same key to do different things in different widgets (eg: F1 calls foo() in one widget, but calls bar() from another)? Or, do you want to make a global binding that will fire no matter whether the focus is in either widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley the problem was connected to displaying parameters in a widget, but you solved it for me in another question yesterday, thank you twice!

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is. Just bind it to two different widgets.

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()

def keypress1(event):
    print event.keysym, " key pressed in root"

def keypress2(event):
    print event.keysym, " key pressed in text"

text = Tkinter.Text(root, width=20, height=20)
root.bind("<Return>", keypress1)
text.bind("<Return>", keypress2)
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Of course, the event has to actually occur in both widgets. I'm not sure whether there's a way to propagate an event captured by one widget to another that didn't capture it. But there are probably better ways to solve your problem than propagating events that way; you can always catch the event in `root` and do whatever you want there.